# Dot-slash not recognized in command prompt - Trying to install Python module

Tags: python, windows, path, command-prompt, python-module

I am trying to install a Python module in command prompt.  The directions state to run "./configure" to install the module and then run a `make` command.  However, whenever I do that, I receive the error

`'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

I am still relatively new to using Command Prompt and Python, so this could be a very novice issue.  From what I've read from other questions, it seems that command prompt should automatically recognize the `./` command, so my only guess is something in my`%PATH%` variable could be tricking it.  Any thoughts or suggestions will be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

EDIT:  Using Windows 7
I have tried using pip as well but it said 'Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement configure`  The module is [poker-engine](http://download.gna.org/pokersource/sources/?C=M;O=D)  I got the most recent version.

Comment: `./` isn't a command, it's the start of the pathname, needed if `.` isn't in `$PATH`. What OS are you on?

Comment: The instructions are for installing it in Linux. You are installing it with those instructions on Windows.

Comment: Ok, well that makes more sense.  How would you do the equivalent on Windows though?

Comment: get the right installation package- for windows: checkhere: http://www.ohloh.net/p/python-poker-engine

Answer (score 7):

Very well answered here - 
[How to fix '.' is not an internal or external command error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20765337/how-to-fix-is-not-an-internal-or-external-command-error)

Trick is to use the command in **double quotes after ./**

I resolved some of my issues as below,

**Example** -

*Change*

```
./node_modules/.bin/coffee -o js -c lib/
```

*To*

```
./"node_modules/.bin/coffee" -o js -c lib/
```

**Another example**

*Change*

```
./node_modules/.bin/browserify demo/browser.js > demo/bundle.js
```

*To*

```
./"node_modules/.bin/browserify" demo/browser.js > demo/bundle.js
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 5):

Your slash should be the other way. ".\configure". I'm having the same problem and this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

try to do

```
configure
```

if you are in the directory where that file is located.

If you aren't in the same folder do this

```
C:\users\myname\path\name\configure
```

If it isn't an exe, change the filetype and windows will run it

Comment: configure doesn't have an extension.  In properties, it says `Type of File: File`.  I tried renaming it to a `*.exe` but got the message `Program too big to fit into memory.`  I also tried just running `configure` as is, but it said configure was not recognized.

Comment: if it has no extension dont type an extension, dont try to convert it either

Comment: @josh forgot to tag you in prev comment

Answer (score 0):

You should really try using pip or easy_install to install the module.  If you can provide the name of the module you are trying to install, perhaps someone can give you more assistance here with regards to how to go about installing it on windows and also add the python version you are using.  You will also find binaries for many Python extensions/modules at this link:
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

If your module is in the list there, go ahead and download it and run the binary.

Comment: @josh the poker-source project that you linked seems to be only usable on Unix/Linux systems. The installation instructions in there have no mention of windows at all.  You could probably try and compile that program in a linux VM on your windows machine or use cygwin that may help in compiling and running the software.  From there home page at http://gna.org/cookbook/?group=pokersource or http://pokersource.sourceforge.net/ I downloaded the poker-engine file and the tarball had a poker-engine directory which contains all the python code written that you could use.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was a combination of Anmol Saraf and Jordan Salinas' answers:

If you have something like this:

`./node_modules/.bin/coffee -o js -c lib/`

You would add quotes around the path after the `./` but also make that forward slash a backslash. So it would now be

`.\"node_modules/.bin/coffee" -o js -c lib/`