# How to fix '.' is not an internal or external command error

Tags: cmd, environment-variables

I have followed few links to try and solve this issue, such as [link1](http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/show/36697-how-to-fix-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-in-windows) , where they have asked to me include the path of the exe in the environment variables. This is the following command I tried, to get this error

```
       D:\Gesture Recognition\Gesture Recognition\Debug>./"Gesture Recognition.exe" 
       rawrec1.trr
```

and the error

```
    '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
     operable program or batch file.
```

I included the gesture recognition exe path into the systems and user variables of the environment variables. Even after booting the system, the error still persisted. Can anybody help me to solve this or fix this?

Comment: Why are you prefixing your command with  `./` on Windows?

Comment: Why do you have the `./`?

Comment: what happens if you remove the . and slash?  `D:\Gesture Recognition\Gesture Recognition\Debug>"Gesture Recognition.exe"`

Comment: try prefixing the command with ".\", `./` only works on Unix-like Operating Systems.

Comment: @AlexejMagura thanks a lot. am so used to working on ubuntu, old habits die hard.

Comment: For me I have this problem in PHPStorm , I have used Gi Bash (Windows) and It works)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Just leave out the "dot-slash" `./`:

```
D:\Gesture Recognition\Gesture Recognition\Debug>"Gesture Recognition.exe"
```

Though, if you wanted to, you could use `.\` and it would work.

```
D:\Gesture Recognition\Gesture Recognition\Debug>.\"Gesture Recognition.exe"
```

Comment: +1, Yes, the folder separator in Windows is \ not /. The use of / is an undocumented feature that only sometimes works. This is one case of many where it does not work.

Comment: Great solution to use the command in double quotes after .\ Very nice. Thanks

Comment: It might be more common to enclose the *whole* path in between quotation marks: `".\Gesture Recognition.exe"`...

Answer (score 15):

Replacing forward(/) slash with backward(\) slash will do the job. The folder separator in Windows is \ not /

Comment: like already described in the accepted answer, more than 3 years ago...

Answer (score 4):

I cloned a repo from github on my windows machine and there command to start cypress was

```
"cypress:open": "../../node_modules/.bin/cypress open"
```

and this was giving me this error

> . . is not recognized as internal or external command

I don't know may be on linux, command may require **node_modules** path as well but on my windows machine just

```
"cypress:open": "cypress open"
```

was sufficient

Comment: The best answer is yours Muhammad. I removed the ./node_modules/.bin/ and now we can run the scripts in windows and Mac. Thanks a lot for your post!!!

Answer (score 2):

I got exactly the same error in Windows 8 while trying to export decision tree digraph using tree.export_graphviz!  Then I installed GraphViz from this [link](http://www.graphviz.org/Download_windows.php). And then I followed the below steps which resolved my issue:

- Right click on My PC >> click on "Change Settings" under "Computer name, domain, and workgroup settings"
- It will open the System Properties window; Goto 'Advanced' tab >> click on 'Environment Variables' >> Under "System Variables" >> select 'Path' and click on 'Edit' >> In 'Variable Value' field, put a semicolon (;) at the end of existing value and then include the path of its installation folder (e.g. ;C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin) >> Click on 'Ok' >> 'Ok' >> 'Ok'
- Restart your PC as environment variables are changed

Answer (score 2):

This error comes when using the following command in Windows. You can simply run the following command by removing the dot `'.'` and the slash `'/'`.

Instead of writing:

`D:\Gesture Recognition\Gesture Recognition\Debug>./"Gesture Recognition.exe"`

Write:

`D:\Gesture Recognition\Gesture Recognition\Debug>"Gesture Recognition.exe"`

Answer (score 2):

I also encountered this issue when working with Webpack. If packages are installed with NPM, ideally you should not have to provide a path to the module that you intend to run. Something like this should work:

```
"build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js",
"start": "webpack serve --config webpack.config.js --open"
```

From my testing, this works in Git Bash, Powershell, and the Command Prompt.

Answer (score 0):

use `.\` instead of `./`. Linux uses forward slash while windows uses backslash. This works in cmd. I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am late to the party, But it can help others
Use `"\\"` instead of `"\"` or `"/"`
it worked for me on windows.

Answer (score 0):

We generally want the script to work on both linux and windows. So, using `./` or `.\` will create problem for one or the other.

Thus, use `child_process` as follows. It works well on all platforms.

```
"preinstall": "node -e \"require('child_process').spawn('sh', ['./preinstall.sh'], { stdio: 'inherit'})\""
```