# '.' is not recognized as internal or external command

Tags: windows, cmd

I am trying to install the Stellar-core on my windows and I'm following the instructions from the site, I configured my windows with git, Clang and GCC and set the PATH variables already. I got to a point where I'm supposed to enter this command `./autogen.sh` and I tried it but I got this error 
`'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` I googled it but couldn't find the solution, I need help on how to fix this error.

Comment: Please copy and paste the exact command you enter from the `cmd` window with the error message it produces.

Comment: `autogen.sh` is a Unix shell script, not a Windows script. What the command does is try to run it, but the Windows command prompt doesn't recognize that syntax (and won't be able to run the script anyway).

Comment: Did you check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20765337/how-to-fix-is-not-an-internal-or-external-command-error?

Comment: `./` is the convention used by Linux. Try with `.\autogen.sh`. Windows uses backslashes, not forward slashes.

Comment: @FabioTurati: It's highly likely that `autogen.sh` is an autotools script, which will not run under the Windows `cmd` shell. The OP needs to follow different directions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you might be following the directions [here](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/blob/master/INSTALL.md) which states:

> Type `./autogen.sh`

However, you appear to be running Windows and should therefore be following the instructions in [INSTALL-Windows.txt](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/blob/master/INSTALL-Windows.txt) instead.

Comment: That's true, thanks a lot. However I just tried the `git clone ...` and I got the error `fatal: repository '...' does not exist`. And I don't understand it. Sorry if the question is stupid but I'm new to this.

Comment: @HughHeimler: The `...` is a placeholder. Simply clone from the github repository just like you did while following the other instructions.

Comment: https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/blob/master/INSTALL-Windows.md