# Npm install not working with gulp

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

Anyone able to guide me on this error? Happens when I run npm i, bower asks me for a version of angular for workspace but I have been installing the specific one required (1.5.8), any help is much appreciated!

```
> workspace@1.0.0 postinstall C:\dev\site
> bower install && ./node_modules/.bin/gulp

'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! workspace@1.0.0 postinstall: `bower install && ./node_modules/.bin/gulp`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the workspace@1.0.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional     logging output above.
```

Comment: try installing gulp globally then use the gulp command instead of the bin in your node_modules directory

Comment: Think this is not a gulp but a windows problem, you might want to replace '/' with '\' in your command ;) See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20765337/how-to-fix-is-not-an-internal-or-external-command-error