# Why is my 'npm start' script resulting in the error: '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.?

Tags: node.js, windows, windows-10, environment-variables

Windows 10
Node v8.1

The project's package.json file consists of a "scripts" object which contains a "start" script that attempts to load nodemon.js from './node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js', but I keep getting this error that "." is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file.

I believe it has something to do with my environment variables, but I'm still confused. Do I need to add a path to my project's node_modules directory in my PATH environment variable?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's enough to use

```
"start": "nodemon"
```

When you run npm scripts it will automatically add the *node_modules/.bin/* folder to the PATH. In that folder there is a script called nodemon.cmd that points to the proper nodemon folder and runs nodemon correctly.

The answer to the question in the title can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20765337/how-to-fix-is-not-an-internal-or-external-command-error).

Comment: I agree, this is normally the case, but I'm trying `npm start` in Windows PowerShell and it can not find the executables, although I've `npm install`ed everything in the project already. It otherwise works perfectly in Linux or macOS. Any ideas?

Comment: I ran into this when I did an npm install and switched to a branch that didn't have that dependency. Doing a fresh npm install didn't seem to pick it up. I resolved the issue by just deleting my node modules folder and doing a clean npm install