# Npm scripts always gives an error as "is not recognized as an internal or external command"

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, lerna

I have a lerna repo. There is devDependency to concurrently package from my root package.json. When I type "lerna bootstrap" to command line,  it works properly and install all root and subPackages` dependencies to root node_modules folder. But when i type "npm start" it says: 'concurrently' is not recognized as an internal or external command. When i check node_modules/concurrently folder it exists without problem.

My start script is `concurrently --kill-others "npm run start-client" "npm run start-server"`.

This situation same with webpack-dev-server. How can i fix this problem except reinstalling everything.

package.json:

```
{
    "name": "x-workspace",
    "private": true,
    "workspaces": [
        "packages/*"
    ],
    "devDependencies": {
        "concurrently": "3.5.0",
        "lerna": "^2.11.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "concurrently --kill-others \"npm run start-client\" \"npm run start-server\"",
        "build": "webpack --hot",
        "start-client": "npm --prefix ./packages/client-app start",
        "start-server": "cd ./packages/server-app && dotnet run",
        "clean": "rimraf node_modules package-lock.json ./packages/client-app/package-lock.json"
    }
}
```

Comment: did u set globally environment variable and path ?

Comment: Did you run `npm install` before you tried to run the project?

Comment: check node is install or not by command "node -v"

Comment: i worked before. But know it does not. I think i set variables and path. How can i check them.

Comment: i have a lerna monorepo. if i type "npm install" it will remove subpackages' dependencies. So i sure all dependencies are installed in node_modules.

Comment: λ node -v
v10.6.0

Comment: Are you running your commands from PS or CMD?

Comment: i have tried both ps and cmd. Result is same

Comment: https://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/fix-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command/ Check this link, I hope it will help you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20765337/how-to-fix-is-not-an-internal-or-external-command-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found problem. There is no .bin folder in root node_modules folder. This is result of updating yarn to 1.8.0. When i return back to yarn 1.6.0, it works perfectly.

Thanks to David R. and other users.

Comment: Great! Please mark this as answered, so that someone might get benefited out in the future. :-)

Comment: It will be possible tomorrow to marking as answered. I will

Answer (score 0):

I believe you don't have the `concurrently` package installed globally, To confirm try executing the below command and check if it returns anything,

```
npm list -g concurrently
```

If you've received an `--(empty)` response, then you'll have to install it globally.

```
npm install -g concurrently
```

Hope this helps!.

Comment: Thx David. This only solves problem with concurrently. But i can not run any command. For example webpack, webpack-dev-server. So i dont want to install all dependencies globally. And it worked before. I broke my system and i want to fix it.

Comment: Can you please update your post with your `package.json` file?

Comment: i added it to my post

Comment: @mehmetbaran Can you please try installing webpack and webpack-dev-server alone  globally as `npm install -g webpack` and `npm install -g webpack-dev-server`?

Comment: i see that if type "npm install" instead of "lerna bootstrap", concurrently works. But webpack-dev-server does not work. Because concurrently is in root package.json. But webpack-dev-server in "package/client-app/package.json" .

Comment: Okay.. One final try, can you please execute `lerna add webpack-dev-server` and see if it works or not?

Comment: It added webpack-dev-server to all packages. But it didn't work. Result is same: 'webpack-dev-server' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174633/discussion-between-david-r-and-mehmet-baran).