# git-bash: '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: windows, git-bash

I have a package.json file where I have start and prestart scripts as follows:

```
"prestart": "./node_modules/react-viro/bin/run_ngrok.sh",
"start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start"
```

But whenever I enter the command npm start in my Git Bash terminal I get an error stating:

> '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

Comment: Have a look at [this Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20765337/how-to-fix-is-not-an-internal-or-external-command-error), you'll find the answer right there.

Comment: Ok. That worked. Sorry for taking your time. But, if I go and change the path for every imported file, then I will have problem syncing with my other friends who use ubuntu instead of windows. Do you know any solution to solve this issue ??

Comment: The best solution would be to define several commands in your `package.json` file, one for each operating system. You could use the colon (`:`) as a delimiter for the OS name, like `"prestart:linux": "./node_modules/react-viro/bin/run_ngrok.sh", "prestart:windows": "node_modules/react-viro/bin/run_ngrok.sh"`. I know this feels very redundant but otherwise you would have to write a shell script yourself which then must be executed by npm...