# Error running npm test command in windows with git bash

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, package.json

I have below `test` command in package.json

```
"test": "rm -rf ./junit.xml && ./node_modules/.bin/react-scripts test --verbose --env=jsdom --testResultsProcessor ./node_modules/jest-junit"
```

Now I am using `windows` laptop and with help of `git bash` tool I am running the command `npm test`.

I am getting below error:

```
> rm -rf ./junit.xml && ./node_modules/.bin/react-scripts test --verbose --env=jsdom --testResultsProcessor ./node_modules/jest-junit

'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

I tried the post - [How to fix '.' is not an internal or external command error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20765337/how-to-fix-is-not-an-internal-or-external-command-error)

and used below options:

```
"test": "rm -rf junit.xml && node_modules/.bin/react-scripts test --verbose --env=jsdom --testResultsProcessor node_modules/jest-junit"
```

I get error as :

```
rm -rf junit.xml && node_modules/.bin/react-scripts test --verbose --env=jsdom --testResultsProcessor node_modules/jest-junit

'node_modules' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

Also this:

```
"test": "rm -rf .\junit.xml && .\node_modules\.bin\react-scripts test --verbose --env=jsdom --testResultsProcessor .\node_modules\jest-junit"
```

I get below error:

```
npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Tell the package author to fix their package.json file. JSON.parse

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-02T10_15_55_006Z-debug.log
```

What is the correct way to use this?

Comment: For instance: `"test": "rm -rf \"./junit.xml\" && \"./node_modules/.bin/react-scripts\" test --verbose --env=jsdom --testResultsProcessor \"./node_modules/jest-junit\""`

Answer (score 0):

You should escape the backslashes like so

```
"test": "rm -rf .\\junit.xml && .\\node_modules\\.bin\\react-scripts test --verbose --env=jsdom --testResultsProcessor .\\node_modules\\jest-junit"
```