# Excluding files for BrowserSync not working

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, browser-sync

I'm currently following John Papa's course on JavaScript Build Automation with GulpJS. At the moment I try to setup [browser-sync](http://www.browsersync.io/) with [gulp-nodemon](https://github.com/JacksonGariety/gulp-nodemon) to keep my browser in sync. This is my gulp task to serve my development build:

```
gulp.task('serve-dev', ['inject'], function () {
    var isDev = true;

    var nodeOptions = {
        script: config.settings.node.server,
        delayTime: 1,
        env: {
            'PORT': port,
            'NODE_ENV': isDev ? 'dev' : 'build'
        },
        watch: [config.server]
    };

    return $.nodemon(nodeOptions)
        .on('restart', ['vet'], function (event) {
            util.log('[nodemon] restarted');
        })
        .on('start', function () {
            util.log('[nodemon] started');
            startBrowserSync();
        })
        .on('crash', function () {
            util.log('[nodemon] crashed', 'red');
        })
        .on('exit', function () {
            util.log('[nodemon] exited cleanly');
        });
});
```

The interesting part is the function `startBrowserSync()`:

```
function startBrowserSync() {
    if (browserSync.active) {
        return;
    }

    util.log('[browser-sync] Starting on port ' + port);

    gulp
        .watch([config.sass], ['styles'])
        .on('change', function (event) {
            util.onChange(event);
        });

    var options = {
        proxy: 'localhost:' + port,
        port: 3000,
        files: [
            config.client + '**/*.*',
            '!' + config.sass,
            config.tmp + '**/*.css'
        ],
        ghostMode: {
            clicks: true,
            location: false,
            forms: true,
            scroll: true
        },
        injectChanges: true,
        logFileChanges: true,
        logLevel: 'debug',
        logPrefix: 'bsp',
        notify: true,
        reloadDelay: 1000
    };

    browserSync(options);
}
```

As you can see in the `files` option I would like to watch all files in the client folder except `*.scss` files and explicitly watch the CSS file in my `.tmp` directory. That's the way John Papa does it in his course. However, everytime I change something in the `*.scss` files the whole page is reloaded. That's not the expected behaviour since I set `injectChanges` to `true` which means to inject CSS and not reload the whole page. The problem is that the `!` does not exclude the files from being watched. What's the problem here?

By the way; My config for sass looks like this:

```
var client = './src/client/';

var config = {
    [...]
    sass: client + 'styles/**/*.scss',
    [...]
}
```

I already took a look into the documentation of BrowserSync [here](http://www.browsersync.io/docs/options/#option-files) and [here](http://www.browsersync.io/docs/options/#option-watchOptions) but even if I use the `watchOptions` property and ignore files it doesn't work.

Anoher problem is that `config.tmp + '**/*.css'` is not working properly. I declared the variable to be `var tmp = './.tmp/';`. Somehow BrowserSync has a problem with the `.tmp`. If I change that to `tmp` only it works. However,  `.tmp` works in all other gulp tasks, e.g. the `styles` task:

```
gulp.task('styles', ['clean-styles'], function () {
    util.log('Compiling SCSS to CSS');

    if (production) {
        config.settings.sass.outputStyle = 'compressed';
    }

    return gulp
        .src(config.sass)
        .pipe($.plumber({
            errorHandler: util.onError
        }))
        .pipe($.sass(config.settings.sass))
        .pipe($.autoprefixer({
            browsers: [
                'last 2 versions',
                '> 5%'
            ]
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.tmp));
});
```

What is the problem here? Any ideas?

**Edit**: Since I am using BrowserSync 2.7.1 I also tried the recommended way of creating the browserSync instance by calling `create()` on the module export. Furthermore I changed the BrowserSync call like so, as stated in [this](http://www.shakyshane.com/javascript/nodejs/2014/01/25/gulpjs-sass-browsersync-ftw/) blog post:

```
 browserSync.init([
            config.client + '**/*.*',
            '!' + config.sass,
            config.tmp + '**/*.css'
        ], options);
```

I removed the `files` property from the options object and passed them as an array in the `init()` function. Still the `scss` files are not ignored and thus the the whole page is reloaded even if there is only a change in the styles.

Comment: Please create a sample project containing your entire gulpfile.js that can replicate this issue and I will look into it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. It was actually crashing because of my path declaration. This is what I had before:

```
var client = './src/client/';
var clientApp = client + 'app/';
var server = './src/server/';
var bower = './bower_components/';
var tmp = './.tmp/';
```

As you can see each path starts with a `./` which only works for non Windows machines since Windows uses `.\` as a command for the current working directory. Maybe it is BrowserSync which does not convert this correctly but for me it works perfectly if I change that as follows:

```
var client = 'src/client/';
var clientApp = client + 'app/';
var server = 'src/server/';
var bower = 'bower_components/';
var tmp = '.tmp/';
```

I removed all `./` from the paths and also changed the way I start BrowserSync to the recommended way as already mentioned in my question edit with a minor refactoring:

```
var files = isDev ? [
    config.client + '**/*.*',
    '!' + config.sass,
    config.tmp + '**/*.css'
] : [];

browserSync.init(files, options);
```

Some sites I stumbled upon gave me the clue to test that out:

- [Tips for Writing Portable Node.js Code](https://gist.github.com/domenic/2790533)
- [Dot-slash not recognized in command prompt - Trying to install Python module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060673/dot-slash-not-recognized-in-command-prompt-trying-to-install-python-module)

If anyone has a better solution to my problem, feel free to add up on my post.

Comment: I am using windows as well. The exclusion is working when the leading './' is dropped. However in my case the config.tmp + '**/*.css' does not pick up the css file in the temp directory. I had to use the path .tmp/styles.css without pattern matching. BrowserSync version is 2.10.1.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else has the same issue I am having, the only way I could get files to exclude was dropping the `./` in the file path.  So as an example, I had to change `./config/*.less` to `config/*.less`, then it would work.

Answer (score 0):

From the browserSync documentation:

```
// Compile sass into CSS & auto-inject into browsers
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src("app/scss/*.scss")
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("app/css"))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});
```

So in the John Papa course, I got it to work by changing my styles task to the following:

```
    gulp.task('styles', ['clean-styles'], function() {
        log('Compiling Less --> CSS');

        return gulp
            .src(config.less)
            .pipe($.less())
            .on('error', errorLogger)
            .pipe($.autoprefixer({browsers: ['last 2 version', '> 5%']}))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(config.temp))
            .pipe(browserSync.stream());
    });
```

Comment: Well but I was looking for the reason why my excluding pattern wasnt working. Nothing about the styles, thats just where my pattern worked.